# Locating one of two characters in a string using indexOf

Tags: c#, backend

I have this array:

```
char[] signOfDecimal = {',', '.'};
```

and I'm trying to find the location of one of these 2 characters in my string:

```
locationOfDotInRate = myString.IndexOf(signOfDecimal[0], signOfDecimal[1]);
```

Basically I'm trying to check where one of these characters might occur in my string, but its not working. The reason I'm doing it this way is because my string sometimes contain '.' or ','.

Comment: Sometimes worth looking at visual studio's intellisense. It shows you already `IndexOfAny` if you enter `myString.IndexOf`

Comment: I can see that you're trying to parse a decimal number that could be from different locales. Watch out! You might get a number such as "1,004" and be unable to tell if that's one thousand and four (where the comma is a thousands separator) or one point zero zero four (where the comma is the decimal mark). If you are SURE that the number cannot contain a thousands separator, you might be OK. But this looks iffy.

Comment: sorry mate but " its not working." is a miserable problem description. You should have writte that you get a `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` then sombody could explain to you that you are actually using [this overload of IndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5xkyx09y(v=vs.110).aspx) and that the second char (`signOfDecimal[1]`) is trated as `int` (UTF-16 representation) which represents: **The search starting position.** That of course assuming that you would like to know why your error arose in the first place

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [IndexOfAny](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.string.indexofany(v=vs.110).aspx) method

```
locationOfDotInRate = myString.IndexOfAny(signOfDecimal);
```